# MySQL Daemon failed to start. ib_logfile is of different size

Tags: mysql

Help me, please.

Server : AWS ec2

**problem :**

```
#sudo service mysqld start

MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

**vi /var/log/mysqld.log :**

```
151015 05:46:26 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
151015  5:46:26 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.45) starting as process 14873 ...
151015  5:46:26 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': signed value 1048576 adjusted to 5242880
151015  5:46:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is d151015 05:46:26 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
151015 05:46:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
151015  5:46:42 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.45) starting as process 15133 ...
151015  5:46:42 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151015  5:46:42 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151015  5:46:42 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151015  5:46:42 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
151015  5:46:42 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
151015  5:46:42 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151015  5:46:42 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 0 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151015  5:46:42 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151015  5:46:42 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151015  5:46:42 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151015  5:46:42 [ERROR] Aborting

151015  5:46:42 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151015 05:46:42 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Thank you!

Comment: Look here http://serverfault.com/questions/379714/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb-mysql-ubuntu

Comment: @Jens This is just a consequence of previous errors. It has nothing to do with the question here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your error:

> InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 0 bytes
>   InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!

Either you adjust the value for `innodb-log-file-size` in your `my.cnf` file to the size of your log files (512M I think), or you simply delete the files `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` in your MySQL folder (most probably `/var/lib/mysql`) and let MySQL recreate them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this occurs because your disk space was full. To check space run..

```
df
```

Try checking a log file somewhere.  Or run the following to find big files...

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100M
```

Once you clear up your disk space try restarting mysql...

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

If it still errors, then try moving the iblog files and then restarting mysql...

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile* ~/
sudo service mysqld restart
```

That should be it in 90% of the cases for this problem. I would avoid messing with your my.cnf file too much.  At worst COPY IT and temporarily put in a very basic version to get more debug...

```
sudo vi /my/etc.cnf

[mysqld_safe]
log_error=/var/log/mysql_error.log

[mysqld]
log_error=/var/log/mysqld_error.log
```